# How to multiple upload video

Tags: python

this is my code but if i run with 1 file upload its work. but if multiple upload cant work. code to input is

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*" multiple="" class="jsx-2751257330 " style="display: none;">
```

and here my python code

```
video_path1 = getFirstFile()
video_path2 = getsecondFile()
print(video_path1)
print(video_path2)
file_paths = f'{video_path1}  {video_path2}'
print(file_paths)
file_input = 
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'input[type="file"]')
file_input.send_keys(file_paths)
```

i need multiple upload same times.